# track criminal payments from Locky

Tags: traceability

A friend of mine is victem of locky ransomware, and is requested to transfer bitcoins. Of course I recommended against it, but it made me wonder what happens if people do follow the instructions.

In particular, are there any wallets known to be related to these criminals/ how could they ever do a sifnificant cashout?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it so difficult to track & recover stolen Bitcoins?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/23109/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-track-recover-stolen-bitcoins)

Comment: A review of the linked question shows that it explains that it may be hard to track back all money in general if people do certain things. I would not say this is a duplicate.